# Multiple feedback posting?

Tags: php, forms, feedback

I made this form for people to leave feedbacks, but when you leave a feedback and refresh/reload the page, it posts it again, and again. Is there any way to make it say something like "The session expired"? Here is the code:

```
<form action="feedback.php" method="POST">
<table width="450px">
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="name">Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comment">Message *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comment" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add FeedBack"> 
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        if($name){
            if($email){
                if($comment){
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (id, name, email, comment) VALUES ('','$name','$email','$comment')");
                }
                else
                    echo "You haven't entered any comment!";
            }
            else
                echo "You haven't entered an email address!";
        }
        else
            echo "You haven't entered your name!";
    }
?>

<?php
    $run = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($run);
    if($numrows > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){
            $dbname = $row['name'];
            $dbcomment = $row['comment'];
            echo "Commented By $dbname<br>$dbcomment<br><br>";
        }
    }
    else
        echo "<br>There are no feedbacks made";
?>
```

Comment: After you do the `INSERT` successfully, do a redirect back to self, which will also stop a page refresh forcing the browser to ask if you wish to resubmit.

Comment: Isn't there another option? I really want the comments and the form to be in the same page..

Comment: @theHazeMaze, yes, you can - see my first comment. You have SQL injection vulnerabilities here though, so do make sure you fix them before going live.

Comment: Oh, are there? Can you please tell me where the vulnerabilities are?

Comment: @theHaze: the vulnerabilities are in each of the `$_POST` variables you are injecting into the query. A malicious user could add SQL in one of them, and potentially execute arbitrary SQL - even database deletions have been known to happen this way. A slight improvement is to escape or untaint user inputs with `mysql_real_escape_string()`, but in some cases even that is not enough - parameterisation is really what you need here. Unfortunately this library does not support it, but since it is deprecated you should switch anyway, to PDO or MySQLi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this based on halfer approach:

**At the top of your page:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        if($name){
            if($email){
                if($comment){
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (id, name, email, comment) VALUES ('','$name','$email','$comment')");
                    //redirect
                    header("Location: mypage.php");
                }
                else
                    $msg = "You haven't entered any comment!";
            }
            else
                $msg = "You haven't entered an email address!";
        }
        else
            $msg = "You haven't entered your name!";
    }
?>
```

**In your HTML code**

```
<?php
    if(isset($msg)) {echo $msg;}
    $run = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($run);
    if($numrows > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){
            $dbname = $row['name'];
            $dbcomment = $row['comment'];
            echo "Commented By $dbname<br>$dbcomment<br><br>";
        }
    }
    else
        echo "<br>There are no feedbacks made";
?>
```

Notice that you aren't redirecting if `!$name` or `!$email` or `!$comment`, which means: the browser will ask for form resubmition when refreshing the page, an event that I describe as ugly. You can redirect if any insertion is made too in order to avoid that:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        if($name){
            if($email){
                if($comment){
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (id, name, email, comment) VALUES ('','$name','$email','$comment')");
                    //redirect
                    header("Location: mypage.php");
                }
                else
                    $msg = "You haven't entered any comment!";
            }
            else
                $msg = "You haven't entered an email address!";
        }
        else
            $msg = "You haven't entered your name!";

        if(isset($msg)) {header("Location: mypage.php?msg=".$msg);}
    }
?>
```

And then:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['msg'])) {echo $_GET['msg'];}
    $run = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($run);
    if($numrows > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){
            $dbname = $row['name'];
            $dbcomment = $row['comment'];
            echo "Commented By $dbname<br>$dbcomment<br><br>";
        }
    }
    else
        echo "<br>There are no feedbacks made";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (id, name, email, comment) VALUES ('','".$name."','".$email."','".$comment."')");

        if($sql == ''){
                    echo "You haven't entered any comment! or You haven't entered an email address! or You haven't entered your name!";
        }
    }

    $run = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($run);
    if($numrows > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run)){
            $dbname = $row['name'];
            $dbcomment = $row['comment'];
            echo "Commented By ".$dbname."<br>".$dbcomment."<br><br>";
        }
    }
    else
        echo "<br>There are no feedbacks made";
?>
```

Comment: As per the comments, this contains a SQL injection vulnerability. If you answer database questions it is worth getting into the habit of spotting them, so you can warn the OP - even if it is not directly connected to the question.